# Position timestamp between two ticks on X-axis

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I have been trying to display data from server on multiple y axes scatter chart. I am receiving it filtered for the past 24 hours, but I am struggling to display it properly because for example single item is created in 23:01 and I need to position it between ticks 23 and 00 on the X-axis.

The following code is example for the past 4 hours, because on this sensor I still don't have data recorded for the past 24 hours:
[image]

The code I have created

```
<ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height="100%">
    <ScatterChart
        width={500}
        height={400}
        margin={{
            top: 10,
            right: 10,
            bottom: 10,
            left: 20,
        }}
    >
        <CartesianGrid />
        <XAxis
            dataKey='created'
            domain={['auto', 'auto']}
            name='created'
            tickFormatter={(unixTime) => moment(unixTime).format('HH')}
            type='number'
        />
        <YAxis yAxisId="left" type="number" dataKey="humidity" name="humidity" unit="%" stroke="#8884d8" />
        <YAxis
            yAxisId="right"
            type="number"
            dataKey="temperature"
            name="temperature"
            unit="°"
            orientation="right"
            stroke="#82ca9d"
        />
        <Tooltip
            cursor={{ strokeDasharray: '3 3', }}
            formatter={(value: any, name: any, props: any) => {
                if (name === 'created') {
                    return moment(value).format('HH:mm');
                } else {
                    return value;
                }
            }}
        />
        <Scatter yAxisId="left" name="A school" data={data} fill="#8884d8" />
        <Scatter yAxisId="right" name="A school" data={data} fill="#82ca9d" />
    </ScatterChart>
</ResponsiveContainer>
```

The data is coming in array of objects:

```
[
  {
   created: 1631199180006,
   humidity: 9,
   idStation: 3,
   name: "Sofia"
   status: "active"
   temperature: 27
  }
]
```

My question is how configure the ticks of the X-Axis to be positioned properly. I have read several posts and in my opinion I should create custom ticks but would be very grateful if someone gives ideas

Comment: I think you have to use tick propoerty inside your X-Axis and pass a custom component :
  <XAxis  dataKey="created" tick={<CustomXAxisTick />}  ....../>